# What are some of the real world uses of Message Authentication Code?

Tags: mac

I have been searching but can't seem to find any proper articles that explain the real world use cases of Message Authentication Code. Can someone please shine some light on this?

Comment: MACs are ubiquitous! For some uses in internet RFCs, try this [Google query](https://google.com/search?q=Message+Authentication+Code+MAC+site%3Aietf.org). The question lacks prior research (and lacked the tag [tag:MAC]).

Answer (score 1):

Before TLS 1.3, most ciphersuites combines an encryption algorithm with HMAC to ensure the content flowing in the session cannot be modified without being detected.

Nowadays, MACs are typically integrated into the encryption algorithm, making them AEADs (Authenticated Encryption with Associated Data), and the stand-alone HMAC is typically used in HKDF to derive key material in secure protocols such as TLS.

Answer (score 0):

Some real world uses of MAC are in IoT when GSM is used for networking, smart metering, health parameter tracking.
It is also used in tls 1.2